# Understanding SwiftUI stacks: Why is there a spacing when items use "maxHeight: .infinity"

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to place different subviews in a `VStack` with a fixed height. The last item should use all the remaining space/height. I found several topics about this, and the solution is simply to give the an `maxHeight: .infinity`.

While this works, I notices that this includes a spacing between this element and the other elements, while there is now spacing between the other elements.

It is no problem to remove this spacing by explicitly defining the stack with `spacing: 0`. However, why is there a space between this item and the others in the first place (while the is no spacing between the other items)?

### Example

```
struct SomeView: View {        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Row 1")
                .background(.red)
            Text("Row 2")
                .background(.green)
            
            Text("Row 3")
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.blue)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 400)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

While there is no spacing between `Row 1` and `Row 2`, giving `Row 3` a maxHeight results in an extra spacing. Why?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried : `VStack(spacing: 0)`

Comment: Yes I did, but it seems that the preview was not updated... This works of cours :-) However, why is there a spacing between 2 and 3 but not between 1 and 2 in the first place? I will rephrase the question accordingly

Comment: Dear @AndreiHerford, according to Apple's docs, when you set ``nil`` to ``spacing`` then default the stack to choose a default distance for each pair of subviews. That's the reason of space. More over you can check to link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/init(alignment:spacing:content:)

Comment: Thanks @bewithyou, I know this pice of the docs but I do not understand why different spacings are applied. So the answer is: "For some reason only Apple knows SwiftUI decides that the default spacing between items 1 + 2 is 0 and some other default value for items 2 + 3"? :-)

Comment: I don't know either this is default distance for each pair by Apple define. And of course, I don't know what they want when they do that :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/init(alignment:spacing:content:)):

> **spacing**
>
> The distance between adjacent subviews, or nil if you want the
> stack to choose a default distance for each pair of subviews.

Let's play around with the element heights (`.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)`) and look at some examples:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StackSpace: View {
    let myRed: Color = .init(red: 1.0, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6)
    let myGreen: Color = .init(red: 0.5, green: 1.0, blue: 0.5)
    let myBlue: Color = .init(red: 0.2, green: 0.9, blue: 1.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Row 1")
                    .background(myRed)
                Text("Row 2")
                    .background(myGreen)
                Text("Row 3 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myBlue)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 120, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)

            VStack {
                Text("Row 1")
                    .background(myRed)
                Text("Row 2 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myGreen)
                Text("Row 3")
                    .background(myBlue)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 120, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)

            VStack {
                Text("Row 1 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myRed)
                Text("Row 2")
                    .background(myGreen)
                Text("Row 3")
                    .background(myBlue)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 120, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Row 1 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myRed)
                Text("Row 2 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myGreen)
                Text("Row 3 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myBlue)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 120, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Row 1")
                    .background(myRed)
                Text("Row 2")
                    .background(myGreen)
                Text("Row 3 - ∞ -")
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(myBlue)
                Text("Row 4")
                    .background(myGreen)
                Text("Row 5")
                    .background(myRed)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: 120, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.yellow)
            
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 300)
        .background(.cyan)
    }
}

struct StackSpace_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackSpace()
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

So, it *appears* that SwiftUI is effectively saying *"This element is bigger than the others, so it should be **prominent** - that is, it should get spacing from its adjacent elements."*

I imagine it's possible there are other properties SwiftUI looks at and determines "this element should be prominent" ...